# As part of development, I am committing to github and pulling down and executing elsewhere. It feels wrong

Tags: python, github, jenkins

I have a standard-ish setup.  Call it three servers - www, app and db, all fed from fabric scripts, and the whole on github.

I have a local laptop with the repo clone.  I change a file locally, and *push it to github* then deploy using jenkins - which pulls from github and does its business.  The problem here is I can put a dozen rubbish commits up till I manage to fix all my typos.

Its not so much the round trip to github that matters, but the sheer number of commits - I cannot squash them as they have been pushed.  It looks ugly.  It works sure but it is ugly.

I don't think I can edit on the servers directly - the file are spread out a lot, and I cannot make each directory on three servers a clone of github and hope to keep things sane.
And trying to write scripts that will synch the servers with my local repo is insane - fabric files took long enough.

I cannot easily git pull *from* jenkins, because I still have to commit to have jenkins pull, and we still get ugly ugly commit logs.

I cannot see a graceful way to do this - ideas anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not use github / jenkins to deploy to the servers.
The servers should be seen as part of the 'local' deployment (local being pre-commit)
So use the fab files directly, from my laptop.

That was harder because of pre processing occuring on jenkins but that is replicable.

So, I shall take Jeff Atwoods advice here

- embrace the suck, in public.

Well I certainly sucked at that - but hey I learnt.

Will put brain in the right way tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is quite simple: make cleaner commits (fix typos before committing, only commit changes that belong together, not for too small edits). It's a bit odd that you don't take the time to fix typos (by running/testing locally) but wish to reduce the number of commits by some other means.

Comment: Not quite what I meant.  typos == bugs I did not catch. Cleaner commits are only possible after I run the code, discover the tests fail etc.  The code is executing on several remote servers.  I run the code, find errors, make it work right.  Then I want to commit.  But I have already committed in process of running the code...

Comment: Then you need to adjust your method of development. You should be able to run and test the code locally without having to commit. If you need to commit to find out if something is working then you need to adjust your local configuration. For most projects you can perform all computations locally as well without commit to a repository.